# Active Record Association after ".where" query

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've got three models: Decks, Slots and Cards. I put them together like so...
Decks are made of many slots, each slot contains one card and any one card can show up in a number of different slots.
I modeled it after the "Order - Order Line Item - Product" structure, hope that makes sense.

Anyways, Decks have an integer field called :deck_type, and suppose I want to get all of the decks of a certain type and then see all of their cards. I EXPECT to be able to run this query but I get an error of undefined method 'cards':

```
Deck.where(:deck_type => 1).cards
```

To get all decks of type 1 and then spit out their cards. I have an association established of "deck has many cards through slots", and when I call ".cards" on a single deck it works fine to return the cards.

I feel like this should be a pretty basic query - what am I missing?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `cards` is for one deck only. So the following should work:

```
Deck.where(deck_type: 1).first.cards
```

The `first` will fetch 1 deck.

If you want cards that belong to decks with deck_type 1, then you've got a few options:

```
Deck.where(deck_type: 1).map(&:cards).flatten.uniq
```

That will apply the `cards` method on each found deck and then get all cards. The flatten will make the results into a 1D array and then uniq will ensure that no duplicates are present, if any.

But the following might be faster:

```
deck_ids = Deck.where(deck_type: 1).pluck(:id)
Card.where(deck_id: deck_ids)
```

I think it's safe to assume your Card model has a deck_id attribute. From the above, you will fetch only those cards that have deck_id in the deck_ids variable.

Even better however would be the following as it'll be a single database query. Assuming you've got the right associations setup, you can do:

```
# replace 'decks' with Deck.table_name if necessary
Card.joins(:deck).where(decks: {deck_type: 1})
```

I hope that last one is self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply and wonderful information - the map and flatten option you presented returns the cards I'm looking for perfectly! I don't have a :deck_id field on the cards table since they're related to the decks through the slots table - does that make sense, or is my model not going to work? Decks have many cards and cards can be in many decks, so I wanted to avoid that many-to-many relationship if possible by putting the slots table between them.

Comment: consider having a relationship between decks and cards so that the last command I wrote can work. It's faster than map(&:cards).flatten.uniq

Comment: Deck model - "has_many :cards, :through => :slots" ... this lets me get cards through decks, but it's more of a challenge to get back to decks through cards since I can't put a "belongs_to :decks, :through => :slots" on the cards model (at least not that I'm aware of). I'm still pretty new to this, though, so learning how .map works is fantastic and lets me use one line to do things that normally would take up several!

Comment: I'm curious. In your Slot model you've got "belongs_to :deck" and in your Card model, you've got "has_many :slots". Is that right?

Comment: Yea, I struggled with the relationships a good bit, but I've got Users, Decks, Slots, Cards, and Editions (eventually I'll have trades, conversations, and who knows what else). It's set up like this - user has many decks, deck belongs to user and has many slots, slot belongs to deck and belongs to card, card has many slots and belongs to edition. It's for a magic the gathering thing I'm working on and with the quantity of cards there are I REALLY wanted to avoid a many-to-many relationship and this was my solution.

Comment: Then in your Card model try the following: `has_many :decks, through: :slots` And then for the join, you'll need to do Card.joins(:decks)

Comment: BRILLIANT! I've been staring at this too close to be able to even see such a simple solution, it's so obvious now! Thank you so much for all of the advice and clarification, you've been a fantastic help.